# How is the measure for the wavefunction determined in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability

Given some quantum mechanical system described by a lagrangian ${\cal L}=\frac{1}{2}\dot{q}^2-V(q)$, I can imagine solving for the wavefunction $\Psi[q]$ and then using this to compute expectation values in the usual way, $\langle q\rangle =\int dq\, |\Psi[q]|^2 q$, for example.  So in the usual case, using $dq$ is the measure for the integral.

However, if I were to redefine my field from $q\to q'$ by, say, defining $q=q'+\epsilon f(q')$ with $\epsilon$ some small constant and $f(q')$ a polynomial starting quadratic in $q'$, and then wanted to compute expectation values of products of $q'$'s, the measure would change.  Rather than integrating $|\Psi[q']|^2$ just against $dq'$ (with $\Psi[q']$ defined by replacing $q=q'+\epsilon f(q')$ everywhere in $\Psi[q]$), I'd have to integrate $dq'$ against $|\frac{dq}{dq'}||\Psi[q']|^2$ due to the Jacobian in changing variables, so the measure is really $dq' |\frac{dq}{dq'}|$ in the new coordinates.

So my questions are:

1. Why is the flat measure, $dq$, the right one to use in the first case?
2. Given a generic lagrangian ${\cal L}(\dot{q},q)$ what is the right measure to use?

If the lagrangian is quadratic in $\dot{q}$ in the form ${\cal L}\supset \frac{1}{2}F(q)^2\dot{q}^2$, then it seems like the right measure to use would be $dq|F(q)|$ or something similar, but what if ${\cal L}$ contains higher powers of $\dot{q}$?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.  Can you re-phrase what you mean?

Comment: My point is the *q'* picture probability density is not merely $|\frac{dq}{dq'}||\Psi[q']|^2$ , but, instead the wave function Ψ should be supplanted by Ψ', the actual solution of the Schroedinger equation in *q'* coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

It's really more accurate to say that $\left|\Psi(q)\right|^2 \operatorname{d}q$ is a parameterization invariant [$(d-1)$-form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form) in a $d$-dimensional space-time. The same can be said of the Lagrangian (density) - it's a paramterization invariant $d$-form.

Put in less technical language, the wave function changes with changes in the coordinate system to maintain the probability predictions whenever it is integrated over a region that is physically the same.

The reason for preferring a flat (i.e. Cartesian) coordinate system in ordinary quantum mechanics is because it has no singularities, and the physical momenta correspond to derivatives along the given direction. When you try to work with, for example, spherical coordinates, things become a good deal more complicated for not much payoff.

The full explanation for how this works comes in quantum field theory, where the Lagrangian is (in every case I'm familiar with) a space-time density that is a function of the fields and is integrated to form the transformation invariant action. In that case, the field can have a conserved charge that corresponds, in the one particle case, to the probability in ordinary quantum mechanics.